# Simple Injector and Web Forms - the correct approach for injecting into Pages, UserControls and MasterPages?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

According to the Simple Injector documentation on WebForms integration, it says, with code examples, that we are supposed to do property injection into our Pages by utilizing the [Import] attribute.  And we enable this behavior by wiring up the Global.asax file according to their code samples.  And it does work for Pages.  There is nothing in the documentation for UserControls or MasterPages, however.

In scouring StackOverflow for a solid answer, the ubiquitous response is slightly outdated and references creating an HttpModule, providing a link to an example project found in their git repo ([SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Forms](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/tree/v3.3.x/src/SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebForms)).  That example project is dead and culled from the repo as of Simple Injector v4.0, though.  And it does not utilize the [Import] attribute stuff at all.  Definitely confusing.

So without a clear idea of how to move forward, I've attempted to merge the two in order to get this working properly.

I am using the Global.asax bootstrapper approach as detailed in the most recent documentation, and not registering a new HttpModule.  I took the [container extension methods](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/v3.3.x/src/SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebForms/SimpleInjectorWebFormExtensions.cs) as defined in the old WebForms integration project, and am calling those in my Bootstrap instead of the old method.

```
   private static void Bootstrap()
    {
    var container = new Container();
//container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior();   //approach from latest documentation
            container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Forms.WebFormsPropertySelectionBehavior(container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior); //changed to using WebForms integration way
    ...
    //RegisterWebPages(ref container); //approach from latest documentation
    container.RegisterPages();       //changed to using WebForms integration extension methods
    }
```

When I first ran it, the container.Verify() complained that every Page implements IDisposable and that they're being registered as Transient (this perplexes me because the original bootstrapping seemed to also register Pages as Transient, but does Verify did not throw any errors).

So, to fix this, I modified the RegisterPages extension method to default to Lifestyle.Scoped, which removed the Verify errors.

```
private static void RegisterBatchAsConcrete(this Container container, IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            foreach (Type concreteType in types)
            {
                //container.Register(concreteType);  //originally registering Transient
                container.Register(concreteType, concreteType, Lifestyle.Scoped);
            }
        }
```

And it seems to work now, at least for Pages.  Before moving forward with getting this working for UserControls and MasterPages, I would like to know answers to the following:

### Questions

Is this the right approach?  Am I going to run into issues (performance, or otherwise) because I changed the Page, MasterPage, and UserControl registration from Transient to Scoped lifestyle?  Are there any other gotcha's I'm not thinking of?

Why does Verify have a problem with Tranisent Lifestyle with the RegisterPages extension method call vs. the new RegisterWebPages method?

Should I actually be using the Import attribute, or no?  The new approach uses the ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior, while the old approach utilizes WebFormsPropertySelectionBehavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That example project is dead and culled from the repo as of Simple Injector v4.0, though.

The `SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Forms)` was built a long time ago and was meant to become the solution for integrating Web Forms with Simple Injector. Since the lack of interest from the community (i.e. there were just too few developers interested in integrating Simple Injector with Web Forms), we decided not to invest in publishing this as NuGet package, maintain it, create documentation, fix bugs, have support for it, etc.

Since Web Forms is a legacy technology, we eventually decided to pull the project from the repository, knowing that we could always reference to older branches.

> And it does not utilize the [Import] attribute stuff at all. Definitely confusing.

That's not true. [Import] will work as well, but as the documentation [describes](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webformsintegration.html), you will have to plug in your custom `ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior`.

> Why does Verify have a problem with Transient Lifestyle with the RegisterPages extension method call vs. the new RegisterWebPages method?

The [integration guide for Web Forms](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webformsintegration.html) suppresses the `DisposableTransientComponent` warning, so that's what you'll have to do as well. The reason this does not happen in the integration project is because this project was created during the v2.x timeframe, and at that time, the verification wasn't that strict. The project has never been updated since.

> Is this the right approach? Am I going to run into issues (performance, or otherwise) because I changed the Page, MasterPage, and UserControl registration from Transient to Scoped lifestyle? Are there any other gotcha's I'm not thinking of?

You should absolutely *not* register your classes and user controlers as scoped, because you will run into serious trouble, really quickly. Especially for user controls, it is really common to have multiple instances of the same control in the page. Registering them as `Scoped` causes the same instance to be placed at multiple places in the page, which will obviously cause trouble (if it works at all).

So you should definately keep user controls (and pages probably as well) registered as `Transient`, and suppress the `DisposableTransientComponent` warning instead. `DisposableTransientComponent` can be suppressed, because ASP.NET will dispose everything for you when the request ends.

> Should I actually be using the Import attribute, or no? The new approach uses the ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior, while the old approach utilizes WebFormsPropertySelectionBehavior

The `ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior` implements [Explicit Property Injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#explicit-property-injection) using the `[Import]` attribute, while `WebFormsPropertySelectionBehavior` implements [Implicit Property Injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#implicit-property-injection).

That decision what to use is up to you, but Explicit Property Injection should in general be preferred, because of the downsides of Implicit Property Injection (that the documentation describes).

Comment: As I typed this up, I was hoping you'd respond, but I didn't expect you to be so quick!

So, to inject into MasterPages and UserControls, should I use the Global asax bootstrap approach (as recommended for Page injection), or the HttpModule approach as recommended in the Integration project?

I understand that WebForms is considered a legacy technology by many, and I do understand why it was pulled from the project.  I am not criticizing that decision - I just want to have a solid answer on how to do this, as I'm sure the other half dozen of us out there still having to use WebForms does.

Comment: Both actually use an IHttpModule, but note that the example in the docs filters out certain handlers, which is something the project doesn't do (because it never really got tested in a real application). So you'll have to mix and match.